# How do I check which present codes I've already entered?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

In Waddle Dee Town, the Waddle Dee-liveries building lets you enter Present Codes to claim Delivery Presents. Each code can only be used once.

Is there a way to check which Present Codes I've already entered?

[image: Waddle Dee-liveries building]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to check if you've used a code is to try entering it.

[image: Waddle Dee says a code was already used]